# I have to refactor my code but don't know where to put collision method

Tags: java, refactoring, collision

I do not natively speak English, so please bear with me and my English. I have made a space invaders game with collision methods. For when the bullets hit walls or enemies, where should I put them? Should I create a whole new class for them or just put the collision methods somewhere with the Enemy class and the Wall class?

This is currently a collision method in my Enemy class, just to show you what I mean and what I am doing. I am trying to make clean and readable code that can easily be reused.

```
 public boolean collide(int i, Player player, BasicBlocks blocks,
        ArrayList<EnemyTypeBasic> enemies) {
    if (enemySprite.isPlay()) {
        if (enemies.get(i).deathScene()) {
            enemies.remove(i);

        }
        return false;
    }
    for (int w = 0; w < player.playerWeapons.weapons.size(); w++) {
        if (enemies != null
                && player.playerWeapons.weapons.get(w).collisionRectangle(
                        ((EnemyTypeBasic) enemies.get(i)).getRect())) {
            enemySprite.resetLimit();
            enemySprite.setAnimationSpeed(120);
            enemySprite.setPlay(true, true); // Object needs to be destroyed
            GameScreen.SCORE += 8;
            GameScreen.lives = 3;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What items can collide? If the only collisions are between bullets and other objects, your collide() method belongs to the class representing bullets.

What I think is more likely, and will be more useful in the long term, is that you will have multiple things that can collide. Maybe bullets collide with ships, but eventually you may want ships to collide with other ships, or with walls. In this case it would make sense to define an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class Collidable {

    public boolean collide(Collidable other) {
        // Here is your logic to check whether *this* is colliding with *other*
        // You will probably need to pass in additional arguments to determine collisions
    }

}
```

Then all of the types which can collide with others extend your abstract class, e.g.:

```
public Player extends Collidable {
    // ...
}

public EnemyTypeBasic extends Collidable {
    // ...
}

public Bullet extends Collidable {
    // ...
}
```

and when you want to check whether two things are colliding you can just call this or equivalent:

```
aBullet.collide(anEnemy)
```

Comment: Much better (in my view) to make `Collidable` an `interface` than an `abstract class`. It's almost certain that players and bullets will have multiple interfaces to implement whereas they can only `extend` one class.